# How to convert Eigen matrix and vector types to Apple's simd types for passing to GPU?

Tags: c++, eigen, simd, metal

I'm trying to use [Eigen's](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) vector and matrix types (like `Vector3f`, `Matrix3f`) for basic graphics-related linear algebra in my application code. But in order to pass them to the GPU, I want to use Apple's Metal API, which takes types from their `<simd/simd.h>` header. They are declared in an odd way that I don't recognize. For example here is the vector of 3 floats, and the 3x3 matrix of floats.

```cpp
// From <simd/vector_types.h>
typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3))) float simd_float3;
...
// From <simd/types.h>
typedef struct { simd_float3 columns[3]; } simd_float3x3;
```

What is the most efficient way to convent an Eigen `Vector3f` to the `simd_float3`, and `Matrix3f` to `simd_float3x3`?

Maybe they are laid out the same in memory and I don't need to convert them? That would be great. Though ideally I'd like to `static_assert` that to double check it with the compiler.

**Edit to Add:**

I assumed I can't use Eigen in the Metal shader code, and that in shader code the only vectors and matrix types that I should use are the simd types - `simd_float3`, `simd_float3x3`, etc. If I could simply use the Eigen types without loss of performance, or major inconvenience, then I might do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metal buffers are not restricted to use `simd` objects only. In fact you pass data via `memcpy` which takes an arbitrary pointer to data, so you can use any types. There are two pitfalls you have to be aware about, though:

1. `simd` objects add one extra element automatically in order to allow matrix/vector multiplication (e.g. `simd::float3` vector in fact contains 4 elements)
2. Eigen objects have to be transposed, otherwise their internal representation doesn't match the expected memory layout. E.g. in order to pass data for 3 vertices of a triangle with:

- `{ -0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f }` - `x`, `y`, `z` of vertex 1;
- `{ 0.0f, -0.8f, 0.0f }` - `x`, `y`, `z` of vertex 2;
- `{ 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f }` - `x`, `y`, `z` of vertex 3;

you are instead supposed to make a 4x3 matrix out of:

- `{ -0.8f, 0.0f, 0.8f }` - values on `x` axis;
- `{ 0.8f, -0.8f, 0.8f }` - values on `y` axis;
- `{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }` - values on `z` axis;

Here is the minimalistic example:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 3> positions{
    { -0.8f, 0.0f, 0.8f },  // x
    { 0.8f, -0.8f, 0.8f },  // y
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },   // z
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }    // w
};  // v1  // v2  // v3

auto* positionsBuffer = metalDevice->newBuffer(positionsDataSize, MTL::ResourceStorageModeManaged);

const std::size_t positionsDataSize = positions.rows() * positions.cols() * sizeof(decltype(positions)::Scalar);

std::memcpy(positionsBuffer->contents(), positions.data(), positionsDataSize );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful info. To your first point, yes, I didn't mean to say I couldn't put Eigen types or anything else into a metal buffer. The issue is that I need types that I can use in the Metal shader code. I assume I can't use Eigen there so either need to convert or reinterpret the data as the simd types. And it looks like it can be done - just need to watch out for that padding you mentioned. I see the Eigen matrix type defaults to `ColMajor` storage, which lines up with the SIMD matrixes.

Comment: About your point #2, we should note that the internal storage does not need to be transposed. That constructor you called with the `initializer_lists` - that does give it row by row, like you did. But if I'm trying to pass a Eigen::Matrix4f as a simd_float4x4, then the data is already in the "column major" order that matches the simd matrixes.